# MySQL (0x80004005) Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts (on non dev machines)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, authentication

I have made a simple login programme which works on the machines I built the program on however when attempting to use the program on other machines this error occurs. 
So far I have ruled out: issues with the connection string, issues with loading MySQL connector .dll's and issues with network configuration. This all leads me to believe it is some sort of permission issue.

All help is appreciated.

side notes: 
Program is in vb.net
database is a MySQL server
server is on the local network

Comment: exactly what error you are getting?

Comment: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

at  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()

Comment: Have you checked whether your mysql db server is running or not? I mean check the `mysqld` daemon in case of unix OR mysql service in services.msc for windows.

Comment: The database is working. using something like MySQL workbench I am able to connect to it no problem like wise when I'm running my program on the dev machine. its only when I move the program to a new machine that this happens

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your MySQL server is not configured to be accessed from net (only local connections).
If you have it installed on Windows server check this 2 things:

```
    1. Check if you have port 3306 opened on firewall
    2. Uncomment in my.ini this line: bind-address=SERVER-IP 
      (replace Server-IP with your server IP address)
```

Comment: the server is intended to only be accessible from the LAN I am experiencing this issue on a local network but ill try anyway thanks

Comment: This procedure is same for LAN as well. MySQL can be configured to be accessible only from PC, where it's installed or from network (LAN or WAN)